# Laravel route [XXX.XXX] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I have a problem access the functions of my controller, only the Controller.index works and all the others not working.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('Publications/datatables', 'publicationController@datatables')->name('Publications-datatables');
Route::resource('publications', 'publicationController');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Publication;
use DataTables;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class publicationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $publications = Publication::get();

        return view('Publications.index', compact('publications'));
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        return view('Publications.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $publication = Publication::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('Publications.show', $publication->id)->with('success', trans('og.alert.success'));
    }

    public function show(Publication $publication)
    {
        return view('Publications.show', compact('publication'));
    }

    public function edit(Publication $publication)
    {
        return view('Publications.edit', compact('publication'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $publication = Publication::find($id);
        $publication->update($data);

        return redirect()->route('Publications.show', $publication->id)->with('success', trans('og.alert.success'));
    }

    public function destroy($id, Request $request)
    {
        if ($publication = Publication::find($id)) {
            $wasDeleted = $publication->delete();
        }

        return redirect()->route('Publications.index')->with('success', trans('og.alert.success'));
    }

    public function datatables()
    {
        $Publications = Publication::all();

        return Datatables::of($Publications)
            ->editColumn('id', '<a href="{{route(\'Publications.show\', ["id" => $id])}}">{{$id}}</a>')
            ->addColumn('actions',
                '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{route(\'Publications.edit\', $id)}}" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . trans('og.button.tooltip.edit') . '" data-title="' . trans('og.button.tooltip.edit') . '" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
               <form style="display:inline" action="{{route(\'Publications.destroy\', $id)}}" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" ><span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . trans('og.button.tooltip.delete') . '"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"  onclick="return confirm(\'' . trans('og.alert.confirm_deletion') . '\')" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button></span></a></form>')
            ->rawColumns(['id', 'actions'])
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors are u getting ?

Comment: @AbdEllatifLakehal Route [Publications.edit] not defined. (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\anotherone\resources\views\Publications\show.blade.php)

Comment: how are you trying to access the `publications.edit` route ?

Comment: by URL : http://localhost/anotherone/public/publications/1
and also http://localhost/anotherone/public/publications/create does not work

Comment: @AbdEllatifLakehal
only the index function works and return data
public function index()
    {   

        $publications = Publication::get();
        return view('Publications.index',compact('publications'));
    }
--------------------------------------------------
@foreach($publications as $pub)
dd(publications );

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `php artisan route:list` to verify your routes? If not, this is what your example generates:

```
| GET|HEAD  | Publications/datatables         | Publications-datatables | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@datatables                  | web        |
| GET|HEAD  | publications                    | publications.index      | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@index                       | web        |
| POST      | publications                    | publications.store      | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@store                       | web        |
| GET|HEAD  | publications/create             | publications.create     | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@create                      | web        |
| PUT|PATCH | publications/{publication}      | publications.update     | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@update                      | web        |
| DELETE    | publications/{publication}      | publications.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@destroy                     | web        |
| GET|HEAD  | publications/{publication}      | publications.show       | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@show                        | web        |
| GET|HEAD  | publications/{publication}/edit | publications.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\publicationController@edit                        | web        |
```

The routes are case sensitive. Perhaps you should use an uppercase 'P" if that's what you are looking to do.

```
Route::resource('Publications', 'publicationController');
```

Comment: If you want your routes to match your controller you should use an uppercase 'P.' Route::resource('Publications', 'publicationController');

Comment: the problem that the function index in the controller works only the others does not

Comment: so i guess there is no problem between the route and the controller matching each other

Comment: What are your views named? There's definitely a problem somewhere. Why are you using "public" in your URL? localhost/anotherone/public/publications/1

Comment: iam not using php artisan serve iam using Xamp so to acces the files i have to add public

Comment: my views names is 1) create.blade.php
2)edit.blade.php
3)show.index.php
4)index.blade.php

Comment: And the folder name?

Comment: file name : Publications

Comment: Do this... Route::resource('Publications', 'publicationController');

Comment: didnt work anymore even the index page who use to work and error come up
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168011/discussion-between-ghassen-arfaoui-and-karl-hill).